# Double underscore functions in Elixir

Tags: elixir

There are some double underscore functions like `__before_compile__` which are automatically called on compile time in Elixir. However, I also see a number of double underscore `__functions__` that seem to be named without magical requirement. For eg, in Ecto, the below functions are called

```
    Ecto.Schema.__source__(source),
    Ecto.Schema.__fields__(fields),
    Ecto.Schema.__assocs__(assocs),
    Ecto.Schema.__primary_key__(primary_key_field),
```

What qualifies these `__functions__` to have, well, double underscores?

ps:  renamed 'methods' to 'functions' after jose's answer. Method is an oop term and is inappropriate here.

Answer (score 20):

The double score functions are used as callbacks (`__before_compile__`, etc) or for metadata (`__info__`, etc). The goal is that they should not pollute your module API. Also functions starting with underscore are not automatically imported (which is what we want here).

PS: they are functions, not methods. :)